# SMAPI add warp to existing map [Stardew Valley]

Tags: c#, modding

I am trying to add a warp into the existing farm map using [SMAPI](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Modding:Index).
I tried the following things but both didn't work.

Setting the Warp inside the map properties:

```
Map farm = Game1.getLocationFromName("Farm").Map;
farm.Properties.TryGetValue("Warp", out PropertyValue initialWarps);
farm.Properties.Remove("Warp");
farm.Properties.Add("Warp", initialWarps + "64 18 TestRoom 5 5");
```

Setting the Warp inside a Tile:

```
Game1.currentLocation.setTileProperty(64, 18, "Back", "Warp", "64 18 TestRoom 5 5");
```

I can confirm that the first approach works when you set the Warp property directly in the map file but it doesn't seem to work if you add it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Until someone finds out how to solve this problem using the build in warp property, i came up with my own solution. It isn't as nice but i thought i am gonna share it with you if someone has the same problem.

ModEntry.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using StardewModdingAPI;
using StardewModdingAPI.Events;
using StardewModdingAPI.Utilities;
using StardewValley;
using xTile;

namespace StardewValleyMod {

    public class ModEntry : Mod {

        private IModHelper helper;
        private WarpManager warpManager;

        public override void Entry(IModHelper helper) {
            this.helper = helper;
            warpManager = new WarpManager();

            warpManager.add(new Warp(new Vector2(60, 15), "Farm", new Vector2(5, 5), "TestRoom"));

            GameEvents.FourthUpdateTick += warpManager.update;
        }
    }
}
```

WarpManager.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using StardewModdingAPI;
using StardewValley;

namespace StardewValleyMod {

    class WarpManager {
        private List<Warp> warps;

        public WarpManager() {
            warps = new List<Warp>();
        }

        public void add(Warp warp) {
            warps.Add(warp);
        }

        public void update(object sender, EventArgs args){
            update();
        }

        public void update() {
            if(Context.IsWorldReady) {
                int x = Game1.player.getStandingX() / Game1.tileSize;
                int y = Game1.player.getStandingY() / Game1.tileSize;

                foreach(Warp warp in warps) {
                    warp.tryToWarp(x, y, Game1.currentLocation.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Warp.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using StardewValley;

namespace StardewValleyMod {

    class Warp {
        private Vector2 from;
        private Vector2 to;
        String fromMap;
        String toMap;
        private int rotation;

        private bool triggerFlag;

        public Warp(Vector2 from, String fromMap, Vector2 to, String toMap, int rotation) : this(from, fromMap, to, toMap) {
            this.rotation = rotation;
        }

        public Warp(Vector2 from, String fromMap, Vector2 to, String toMap) {
            this.from = from;
            this.to = to;
            this.fromMap = fromMap;
            this.toMap = toMap;
            rotation = 2;
        }

        public bool tryToWarp(int x, int y, String mapName) {
            if(!triggerFlag) {
                if(x == from.X && y == from.Y && mapName.Equals(fromMap)) {
                    Game1.warpFarmer(toMap, (int) to.X, (int) to.Y, (int) rotation);
                    triggerFlag = true;
                    return true;
                }
            } else if(!mapName.Equals(fromMap)) {
                triggerFlag = false;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I bhave figured out:

```
List<Warp> warps = new List<Warp>();
warps.Add(new Warp(5, 53, "BusStop", 34, 23, false));
warps.Add(new Warp(5, 54, "BusStop", 34, 23, false));
warps.Add(new Warp(5, 55, "BusStop", 34, 23, false));

foreach (Warp warpy in warps)
{
  location.warps.Add(warpy);
}
```